# Air/Acetonitrile Interfaces

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents, intermolecular-forces, polarity

Say I drop some acetonitrile on a grounded surface and it forms a meniscus. The acetonitrile is in air. Lets forget about evaporation for the moment.

1. Will there be an interfacial dipole formed by the orientation of acetonitrile at the surface with the air?
2. If so, what would be the strength of that dipole be? What temperature/diffusion would be enough to overcome that orientaiton.

Comment: Add more context to the question. What is purpose of dropping ACN on a grounded Al plate?

Comment: The Al was just a distraction (removed now). I'm interested in the orientation of the dipole layer (if it forms) at the surface of ACN. I'm not sure how to go about understanding that.

Comment: These seems relevant (second behind paywall sadly) - but doesn't really solve the problem. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j100541a015 and http://www.columbia.edu/cu/chemistry/fac-bios/eisenthal/group/pdf-files/JPCC_2009.pdf

Comment: Have you discussed this with your supervisor? This is why I was asking for a context. Is this a PhD or MS or BS project or just a classroom curiousity? In short, this is not something which can be answered on a web-post (and I don't know much about it). The first paper is behind pay-wall not the second one.

Comment: Just a curiosity. I naively thought dipoles would be quite easy to calculate from the charge distribution of the solvent molecule, or at least an idea if the dipole even exists! Thought the community would have a general idea of the surface of common solvents!....